# ¿Por que "primo" es un "Hombre de raza negra"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

El diccionario de la RAE recoge como sexta acepción de [**primo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UBQk8bX):

> 6. m. coloq. p. us. **Hombre de raza negra**.

que, aparentemente, no tiene  relación con ninguna de las 20 restantes acepciones.
¿De donde procede ese uso?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Una pregunta que nos ha dejado a todos anonadados, sin duda. Gran descubrimiento, esperamos que todas tus aportaciones a este sitio sean igual de interesantes. :-)

Comment: Quizás es como "Brother," "Sister," en inglés, que puede decir una persona negra para reconocer que la otra persona negra, quizás deconocida, forma parte de la misma sub-tribu.  Por lo menos en EEUU.  No sé si también en el mundo británico.

Answer (score 4):

Consultado a la propia RAE:

> La acepción de primo con el sentido de ‘persona de raza negra’ apenas
>   tiene ya uso, por lo que en el diccionario porta la marca de poco
>   usado, al margen de la de coloquial. Figura en el diccionario
>   académico desde el llamado Diccionario de Autoridades, primera obra
>   académica, publicada en el siglo XVIII, y ya se mencionaba en este
>   diccionario el carácter festivo de tal acepción. Se documentaba
>   siempre en textos con intención humorística. Valgan algunos
>   testimonios en los que se puede comprobar el uso mencionado:
>
> **c1638** ROJAS ZORRILLA, FRANCISCO DE Entre bobos anda el juego (ESPAÑA).
>   
>   Pues si un hermano no vale,
>   ¿cómo ha de valer un **primo**,  que es
>   
>   parentesco de negros?
>
> **1661** MORETO, AGUSTÍN La fuerza del natural (ESPAÑA).
>   
>   Pues picaron atrevido, 
>   
>   ¿vos con mi **prima** y mi **prima** 
>   
>   con vos? somos todos **primos** 
>   
>   o negros? Carlos 
>   
>   Señor, yo aora 
>   
>   leal y atento resisto 
>   
>   que Aurora con Alexandro 
>   
>   se case, quando contigo 
>   
>   logrará tan justo empleo.  […]

Al parecer su uso fue humorista, por los escritores en siglos anteriores, O bueno eso es lo que puedo recabar de esta respuesta.

También puedes corroborarlo haciendo la consulta por cuenta propia llenando el siguiente formulario
[Consultas lingüísticas](http://www.rae.es/formulario/consultas-linguisticas)

Comment: Muy interesante. El primer ejemplo parece corroborar mi suposición de que se usaba en contraposición a "hermano".

Answer (score 2):

Puede que esta sea de esas cuestiones que van a ser difíciles de dilucidar. Normalmente en este tipo de investigaciones se pueden encontrar datos de la evolución de un significado concreto a lo largo del tiempo, reflejados en las diferentes ediciones del DLE. Sin embargo, en este caso nos encontramos en el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1737) con una definición similar a la actual:

> En el estilo festivo llaman al negro ò Ethíope.

Se ve que dicha definición ha ido pasando a lo largo de los diccionarios hasta llegar a día de hoy. El hecho de que esté marcada como "poco usada" no me deja claro si se refiere a que hoy es poco usada o si ha sido poco usada a lo largo del tiempo. En cuanto a diccionarios anteriores, no hay ninguno que recoja esta acepción.

Normalmente suelo buscar en el CORDE algún ejemplo, pero por más que lo intento no me sale nada. Así que ya solo me queda la especulación, y es que (dado que la definición está marcada como festiva o jocosa) se llamaran así a las personas de raza negra en contraposición al término "hermano". Los hermanos se suelen parecer más entre sí, mientras que los primos se parecen menos (aunque conservan el aire de familia). De ahí que a las personas cuyo color de piel difería de lo que estaban acostumbrados les llamasen "primos", dado que no se parecían tanto a ellos como sus "hermanos" blancos.

Una respuesta un tanto políticamente incorrecta, pero es lo que se me ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Antiguamente *primo* también era una forma coloquial de referirse a un "sujeto cándido, sencillo y crédulo a quien se engaña fácilmente" (véase [aquí](https://books.google.cl/books?id=e8dLAAAAcAAJ&dq=primo%20primitivo%20negro&pg=PA1422#v=onepage&q=primo%20primitivo%20negro&f=false) y [aquí](https://books.google.cl/books?id=JEJBMvZI2OYC&dq=primo%20primitivo%20negro&pg=PA434#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Corominas cree que era una ironía, a partir de uno de los significados originales de primo: "sutil, primoroso", es decir, de *primera* calidad.

Puede ser, por lo tanto, que a los negros les haya quedado ese mote por ser gente culturalmente menos sofisticada que los europeos de antaño, de la cual se reían diciéndoles "primeros" por decirles "rústicos". Es una idea.

Comment: Esa acepción de **primo** (*sujeto cándido etc.*) aparece por primera vez en el DRAE de **1852**, mientras que la acepción por la que se pregunta (*hombre de raza negra*) la predata en más de 100 años, ya que ya figura en el Diccionario de Autoridades (**1737**) y en textos anteriores como recoge la respuesta de @MiguelAngel. No es verosimil que la acepción más tardía  diera origen a la más temprana - si acaso, al revés [aunque eso sería tema para otra pregunta]

Comment: @Leonardo Tienes toda la razón. En todo caso, que esta misma ironía haya existido desde antes sigue siendo posible, aunque no sea demostrable.